# Difference between doc.field_name vs field_name in Elastic Search?

Tags: elasticsearch, querydsl

I have a source like this :

```
{
      "doc" : {
        "questions" : [
          {
            "question" : "Which gold customers in Texas had bank accounts with more than $10 million last year ?",
            "state" : "COMPLETED",
            "tags" : [
              "computer"
            ]
          }
        ]
      }
    }
```

When I write a query for searching based on state and tag ,the query looks like this ,

```
 {
  "size": "2000",
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "must": [
        {
          "match": {
            "doc.questions.state": "COMPLETED"
          }
        },
        {
          "match": {
            "doc.questions.tags": "computer"
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  },
  "from": "0",
  "_source": {
    "includes": [
      "doc.questions.question",
      "doc.questions.state",
      "doc.questions.tags"
    ]
  }
}
```

Why is it required to write **doc.questions.tag** instead of **questions.tags** ?

If i remove **doc.** from any keys, nothing matches

[image]

***Where is the difference ?***

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Basically Elasticsearch has two variants of *JSON inside a JSON structure* i.e. a [`nested`](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/nested.html) or [`object`](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/object.html) type.

In your case it is an `object` type. You can verify the [*mapping*](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/mapping.html) or in RDBMS terms the *schema* of that *index* using

```
GET <your_index_name>/_mapping
```

In order to search based on the values of the inner json structure, **you need to** include ***the entire path of the field*** otherwise elasticsearch would treat `questions` as if its a field outside `doc`.

So if your JSON structure is as below, it would work by removing `doc`.

```
{
   "questions":[
      {
         "question":"Sample Question",
         "state":"Completed",
         "tags":[
            "computer"
         ]
      }
   ]
}
```

Hope you understand now as why you would not get any results quite simply because your JSON structure for `questions` starts from `doc`.

The links I've shared would help you clarify. Hope that helps!

Comment: Hi @Opster , Regarding : "So if your JSON structure is as below, it would work by removing doc".

questions.question works,
but for questions.tags. doesn't work for me. To make it work I need to use doc.questions.tags.

Comment: For the JSON you've mentioned in your question, you need `doc.question.tags` as well as `doc.question.questions`. You need to mention **the entire path** from which your JSON starts.

Answer (score 0):

On top of Kamal's remarks, it's generally bad practice to use the semi-reserved keyword `doc` inside your documents!

`Doc` is for instance used as the top-level [doc_values](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/master/doc-values.html) context [within scripts](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/master/modules-scripting-fields.html#modules-scripting-doc-vals) like so:

```
GET my_index/_search
{
  "script_fields": {
    "sales_price": {
      "script": {
        "lang":   "expression",
        "source": "doc['cost_price'] * markup",    <---
        "params": {
          "markup": 0.2
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

which means it'd be easy to confuse with the *doc* inside your actual document. So rename to be more descriptive... Everything out here is a "doc" ;)

Comment: I think you didnt get my question :( @jzzfs